# Removing string between special characters in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove the string which is placed in between "^".

my code:

```
$search = "/[^](.*)[^]/";
$replace = "";
$string = "^5561^18.5018,73.8636|^5662^20.1738,72.7640";
echo preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
```

but my output: ^^..^^..

desired output: "8.5018,73.8636|20.1738,72.7640";

pls let me know how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe explode string first with "|" and then replace.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^]` pattern is an invalid character class. In JavaScript, it would match any char since it is parsed as a *non-nothing*, but in PHP, it is an empty (and thus invalid) negated character class.

You need to match `^` with `\^` and either use a lazy dot pattern or a `[^^]*` to match any chars but `^` in between:

```
$search = '/\^[^^]*\^/';
$replace = "";
$string = "^5561^18.5018,73.8636|^5662^20.1738,72.7640";
echo preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
// => 18.5018,73.8636|20.1738,72.7640
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/8CZLS5).

**Details**

- `\^` - a `^` char
- `[^^]*` - any 0+ chars other than `^` (the first `^` denoted a negated character class and the second one is a literal `^`)
- `\^` - a `^` char.